# How to map at more sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

hi I'm doing a little review of set theory and wondered if were possible  to map at n codomains starting from a single domain?

Comment: You might try defining several related functions using indices. Something like: For all $i\in I$, $f_i: X\to Y_i$

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this is via a function into a cartesian product, for example $f:X\to(Y\times Z)$, so that for each $x\in X$, $f(x)=\langle y,z\rangle$ for some $y\in Y,z\in Z$. These $y,z$ values are uniquely defined and so induce projected functions $f_1:X\to Y,f_2:X\to Z$ satisfying $f(x)=\langle f_1(x),f_2(x)\rangle$ for all $x\in X$. These projections can also be established directly as $f_1=\pi_1\circ f$, $f_2=\pi_2\circ f$ where $\pi_1:(Y\times Z)\to Y,\pi_2:(Y\times Z)\to Z$ are the standard projection functions defined by $\pi_1(y,z)=y$, $\pi_1(y,z)=z$.

This exact same analysis applies with some generalization to arbitrary cartesian products $\prod_{i\in A} Y_i$, where now we have a projection operator into each factor $\pi_k:\prod_{i\in A} Y_i\to Y_k$, and every function $f:X\to\prod_{i\in A} Y_i$ factors into a tuple of functions $f_k=\pi_k\circ f:X\to Y_k$ such that $f(x)=(i\in A\mapsto f_i(x))$ for each $x$.

Comment: f1 and f2 are the images of f belonging at Y and Z, with arguments x. In practice can be considered a vector valued map right?

Comment: @Jyanluka The function $f$ is exactly a vector-valued map (although this term can also be applied to functions into vector spaces that may not be explicitly a cartesian product). Strictly speaking $f_1$ and $f_2$ are not images of $f$ - an image of $f$ would be a subset of $Y\times Z$ - but they are projections of $f$.